# Assign start and end time to Table cell <td> and check current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table that will have start and end times of certain events. Is there a way of assigning a start and end time to each table cell, and then checking whether the current time is after the time in each cell?

```
<table class="ui celled  blue table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Monday</th>
      <th>Tuesday</th>
      <th>Wednesday</th>
      <th>Thursday</th>
      <th>Friday</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
     <td class="clickable">08:30 - 09:30 Meeting</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: There is. You would need to convert the string value in the cell to a Date object, then compare it to the current Date. If you can add your HTML and any existing code you have to your question people will be able to help more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code to give me more idea of what you are trying to do ... but something like this will work (using jQuery), if you need raw JavaScript post back and I will convert it.

```
var now = new Date();
$('table#tableid td').each(function()
{
  var td = $(this);

  // get cell text or assign start and end date to the cell
  // like this to add it as an attribute
  // td.attr('data-start-date', new Date());

  // to get an attribute you can use
  // var start = td.attr('data-start-date'); 
  // where there is an attribute data-start-date on the td element

  var date = new Date(td.text()); // you may need to consider date format string of the cell text
  if(date > now)
  {
    console.log(date + ' is after now.');
    // you could also color the cell if you needed like
    td.addClass('green'); // then create a css class for .green { background: green; }
  }
});
```

JavaScript Date object documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

**An example that parses your cell text**

[A 'simple' JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/hixipavayu/2/) which assumes 24 hour time in the cell text. Change some cell values and you will see green. Also there is no validation around dates - e.g., start is after end.

Note my recommendation (in the notes, about attributes) as string parsing is nasty and if it can be avoided it should be.

A library that is useful (easy to use) for date manipulation is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
$(function()
{
  var now = new Date(); 

  var getTimeFromString = function(timeStr)
  {
    var split = timeStr.split(':');
    return { 
      hour: split[0], 
      minute: split[1] 
    };
  };

  var getTimeFromCellText = function(text)
  {    
    var split = text.split(' ');    
    var time = 
    {
      start: getTimeFromString(split[0]),
      end: getTimeFromString(split[2])
    };

    return time;
  };

  $('table.celled td').each( 
    function() 
    {
      var td = $(this);
      var time = getTimeFromCellText(td.text()); 

      var start = new Date(now);
      start.setHours(time.start.hour);
      start.setMinutes(time.start.minute);

      var end = new Date(now);
      end.setHours(time.end.hour);
      end.setMinutes(time.end.minute);

      if(now > start && now < end)
      {
        td.addClass('green');   
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I added the HTML table, each time will be different of course. Just something along those lines.

Comment: They are times not dates, do you also have a date somewhere or do you just want to know if the current time is between the cell text appointment times? Also are you generating this from server code? If so, you should add the times as attributes so you don't have to parse the cell text.